# Update all DATETIME fields in the database

Tags: mysql

I'm currently storing all `DATETIME` fields in my database in US Eastern time, and would like to `UPDATE` them all to UTC. I have a lot of `DATETIME` fields in lots of different tables. Is there a way to identify and `UPDATE` them all at once?

Comment: You could build those queries by a query on the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/columns-table.html) table.

Comment: The comment from @VMai is correct, with [21.4 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/columns-table.html), [13.6.6 Cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cursors.html) and [13.5.1 PREPARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/prepare.html), all in [13.1.15 CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html) - (Stored Procedure), think you can achieve what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate the UPDATE statements that you need with following statements:

```
SET @tzdiff = 5;    -- difference between EST and UTC
SET @db = 'test4';  -- your DB name
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        'UPDATE ',
        '`', c.TABLE_NAME, '` ', 
        'SET ', 
        '`', COLUMN_NAME, '` = ',
        '`', COLUMN_NAME, '` + INTERVAL ', @tzdiff, ' HOUR;' 
    ) as update_statement
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE
    c.TABLE_SCHEMA = @db
AND
    c.`DATA_TYPE` LIKE 'datetime';
```

Result for my database 'test4':

```
update_statement
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE `example12` SET `column_name` = `column_name` + INTERVAL 5 HOUR;
UPDATE `post` SET `expiration` = `expiration` + INTERVAL 5 HOUR;
```

For a one-time-job, I would simply copy the result into the MySQL client of your choice and execute them. Of course it's possible to create prepared statements for the results and execute them.